# VBA module stops seemingly without reason.

Tags: vba

I have this VBA code which ends right after the big for loop, before "msgbox "h". The msgbox is to check if it continues. The code runs through the loop but nothing more. Can someone please help me understand why?

```
Sub countPT()
'Select file
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i As Integer, lastRow As Integer, tellerPoE(13) As Integer, 
telleruPoE(13) As Integer, SwitchInd As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim krrom As String, Comment As String

    For i = 1 To 13
        tellerPoE(i) = 0
        telleruPoE(i) = 0
    Next i

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    openFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xls*", 1, _
        "Select a file to open", , False)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Len(openFile) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
        End
    End If
    Workbooks.Open openFile

    Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook


'Read through and count -> put to array on index
    lastRow = wb2.Worksheets("Rådata").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 114 To lastRow
        wb2.Activate
        If CStr(wb2.Worksheets("Rådata").Cells(i, "G")) = "528" Then
            krrom = CStr(wb2.Worksheets("Rådata").Cells(i, "F"))
            SwitchInd = SwitchCode(krrom)
            'If SwitchInd = 0 Then
                'GoTo ContinueLoop
            'End If

            Comment = LCase(CStr(wb2.Worksheets("Rådata").Cells(i, "M")))

            If (InStr(Comment, "poe") Or InStr(Comment, "kamera") Or 
InStr(Comment, "cam")) Then
                If Len(wb2.Worksheets("Rådata").Cells(i, "L").Value) > 0 Then
                    tellerPoE(SwitchInd) = tellerPoE(SwitchInd) + 1
                End If
                tellerPoE(SwitchInd) = tellerPoE(SwitchInd) + 1
            Else
                If Len(wb2.Worksheets("Rådata").Cells(i, "L").Value) > 0 Then
                    telleruPoE(SwitchInd) = telleruPoE(SwitchInd) + 1
                End If
                telleruPoE(SwitchInd) = telleruPoE(SwitchInd) + 1
            End If


'ContinueLoop

        End If
    Next i

'Check up to existing
    'Update values
    'Give message on change

    MsgBox "h"
    For j = 1 To 13
        If tellerPoE(j) > CInt(Cells(5 + j, "E")) * 2 Or telleruPoE(j) > 
CInt(Cells(5 + j, "G")) Then
            Cells(6 + j, "K") = "Punkter økt"
        End If
        Cells(5 + j, "E") = tellerPoE(j)
        Cells(5 + j, "G") = telleruPoE(j)
     Next j

'Empty and close
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    wb2.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Some of the code are commented out as to try to fix the problem or make it easier to find blocks

Comment: Have you debugged your code? If the `msgBox`-statement is not reached, there must be something that causes the `quit`. You could add a `Debug.Print i`statement at the top of the loop to check if it is executed as expected. An advice: declare numbers as `long` rather than  `integer` to prevent overflow.

Comment: I've tried like it is. Since the lastRow is above 4500 I tried ending the for loop 120 which now makes it continue after the for loop. So the problem is why it won't work when it ends at above 4500

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Works now

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem, just a comment on the code:  you have two lines of code just before your big loop - `Workbooks.Open openFile: Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook`.  This could be written as `Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(openFile)`.  No chance of the wb2 being set to the wrong book then.

Answer (score 0):

After the `MsgBox`, delete the loop and write the following:

```
MsgBox "h"
For j = 1 To 13
    Cells(6 + j, "K") = "Punkter økt"
Next j
```

check whether it produces what you need. If it does, then it works and your condition is wrong.

Comment: The problem is just that the code never even gets to the msgbox and so never runs that nor the rest

Comment: @tarethe - I see. This line seems pretty wrong, it should be on one line -    `If (InStr(Comment, "poe") Or InStr(Comment, "kamera") Or 
InStr(Comment, "cam")) Then` In general, try to build up a code with simple fake values and check with F8, step by step where the problem is.

Comment: The If shood work properly now. Running through the code in debug mode with F8 just stops before the msgbox "h" line. No error, nothing.. just like there's no more lines

Comment: @tarethe - try to delete as much as you can from your code to replicate the issue. Then make it about 10 lines. Then update your question with it.

Comment: Fixed some of the lines you pointed out and it works like a charm now. Turned out to be some bad written If sentences. Thank you!